# Generating Random Doubles in Java

Tags: java, double

I'm a Java noob trying to generate a random double between -10 and 10 inclusive. I know with ints I would do the following:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
int i = -10 + r.nextInt(21);
```

However, with doubles, this doesn't work:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
double i = -10 + r.nextDouble(21);
```

Can someone please explain what to do in the case of doubles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Random r = new Random(); 
    double d = -10.0 + r.nextDouble() * 20.0;
```

Note: it should be 20.0 (not 21.0)

Comment: Thank you! Just curious though, why should it be 20 instead of 21? Should it be 20 in the int example also?

Comment: Because otherwise the minimum value is `-10 + 0.0*20.0` (-10.0) and the maximum is `-10 + 1.0*21.0` (11.0)...

Comment: And the int example should indeed be `nextInt(21)` since the `Random` doc for this method says that nextInt returns an int *value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)*. Are you happy with this answer?

Comment: This will never return 10 since `nextDouble()` can't return 1. `-10.0 + 0.999... * 20.0 != 10`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this for generate values in given range:

```
Random random = new Random();
double value = min + (max - min) * random.nextDouble();
```

Or try to use this:

```
public double doubleRandomInclusive(double max, double min) {
   double r = Math.random();
   if (r < 0.5) {
      return ((1 - Math.random()) * (max - min) + min);
   }
   return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: nextDouble() returns from 0.0d (inclusive) to 1.0d (exclusive) so it can never return `max` value.

Comment: @Pshemo answer is updated.

Comment: +1 I like this "hack" although numbers other than 0 and 1 have two times higher chance to be randomed :)

Comment: The first set worked best for me, just due to it's simplicity. I would recommend replacing this as the correct answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> > Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

nextDouble doesn't take a parameter, you just need to multiply it by whatever your range is.  Or more generally:

```
minimum + (maximum - minimum) * r.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `nextDouble(int)` method in `Random`. Use this:

```
double i = -10.0 + r.nextDouble() * 20.0;
```

[API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29)

Comment: Wrong, this can give values over 10.0

Comment: `i` will be in [-10; 10).

Comment: It said 21, I think you editted it?