# Java Random.nextDouble() probability

Tags: java, random, probability

I'm trying to get random double numbers between 1.0 and 10.0 using the `Random.nextDouble()` as such:

```
double number = 1.0 + (10.0-1.0) * Random.nextDouble();
```

Simulating this 10,000 times I find out that the probability of 1.0 and 10.0 is lower than the rest. The only way to get these number would require `Random.nextDouble()` to be either 0.0 or 1.0. So essentially since `Random.nextDouble()` gives a random number inbetween 0.0 and 1.0 it's less likely to actually result in 0.0 or 1.0.

Is there a way to mend this I wonder? Or should I try a completely different way as a whole?

EDIT:

So the problem lied indeed with rounding the numbers off to 1 decimal after generating a random double. A very crude solution I did now instead was generate a `randomIntValue` between 0 and 91 and then initialise the `double number = 1.0 + (randomIntValue * 0.1)` as such.

This is not the cleanest option i'd say.

Comment: There are a ton of questions on this already. Google how to generate a random number in a range in Java.

Comment: Are there? Where?

Comment: @Bathsheba if you Google like I said... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055624/generating-random-doubles-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723765/generating-a-random-double-number-of-a-certain-range-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680637/generate-a-random-double-in-a-range

Comment: The OP appears to be aware of those. I read this as more of a floating point pitfall question.

Comment: nextDouble can produce 0.0 but it can't produce 1.0, all values are equally likely. Note: there is 2^48 possible values for `Random` and a sample of 10,000 is unlikely to be meaningful.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Increasing the simulations to either 100,000 or even 10,000,000 still shows 1.0 and 10.0 giving about half of the results of all other 89 possible numbers. (ex. 1.0 = 55,523, 1.1 = 110,744)

Comment: That would happen if you round the results. say you round to one decimal place, 1.0 would be half as likely as 1.1 as 1.1 has values which round up and round down to 1.1. To get 10.0 you need 9.95 or higher. In short, nothing rounds up to 1.0 and nothing rounds down to 10.0. If you truncate the number  you will find 1.0 is as likely as 1.1 but 10.0 won't appear at all.

Answer (score 1):

The first point to note is that `(10.0-1.0)` is *exactly* `9.0` in IEEE754 double precision floating point.

The next point to note is that `Random.nextDouble()` returns a number strictly less than `1.0` but greater than or equal to `0.0`. It will *never* draw `1.0`.

So we can confidently write your expression as

`1.0 + 9.0 * Random.nextDouble()`.

The fact that this will *occasionally* draw `10.0` is due to floating point imprecision (in this case an unwanted round-up to the nearest floating point number). Essentially this probability is "borrowed" from the `1.0` drawing. This will be the case even if the random number generator was perfect.

There is not a "one solution fits all" solution to floating point issues. In this case, if your application really cannot tolerate the occasional `10.0` then you could "give back" that drawing to the `1.0` case. But do check that the resulting generator has the required statistical properties.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lied indeed with rounding the numbers off to 1 decimal after generating a random double. A very crude solution I did now instead was generate a `randomIntValue` between 0 and 91 and then initialise the `double number = 1.0 + (randomIntValue * 0.1)` as such.

This is not the cleanest option i'd say.